# Open question about limits of functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, functions, convergence-divergence

I came across something today that to my surprise I had never seen before. Basically I had a sequence of continuous functions $f_i \rightarrow f$, all from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and a convergent sequence $x_i$ in $[0,1]$. I then had to take the limit of $f_i(x_i)$. I have the fairly strong conditions that all the $f_i$ are continuous and converge uniformly but I'm still not fully convinced that this will convergence to $f(x)$.

I was also wondering what would happen if we abandon these conditions. Does anyone have any knowledge about this?

Comment: With non-uniform convergence you cannot expect such result: consider the famous example $f_n(x)=1-nx$ for $x\le 1/n$

Comment: @user251257 he asked "what would happen if we abandon these conditions". With uniform convergence result is quite easy to prove, I believe.

Comment: Ah, it's indeed quite easy to prove this in the case of uniform convergence. Would the converse also be true though?

Answer (score 0):

If $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ then given $\epsilon>0$ we have that

$$\exists N\in\mathbb{N}: n\ge N_1\implies |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon.$$

Assume $x_n$ converges to $x_0.$ Since $f$ is continuous  given $\epsilon>0$ we have that

$$\exists \delta>0: |x-x_0|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon.$$

Since $x_n$ converges to $x_0$ then given $\delta>0$ we have that

$$\exists N_2\in\mathbb{N}: n\ge N_1\implies |x_n-x_0|<\delta.$$

Thus

$$n\ge \max\{N_1,N_2\}\implies |f_n(x_n)-f(x_0)|\le |f_n(x)-f(x)|+|f(x)-f(x_0)|<2\epsilon.$$ So, we have shown that $f_n(x_n)$ converges to $f(x_0).$

If we don't assume uniform convergence then the result doesn't hold. Consider $f_n(x)=x^n$ on $[0,1].$ The sequence $(f_n)$ converges pointwise to $f(x)=0,x\in [0,1),f(1)=1.$ Consider the sequence $x_n=1-\frac1n.$ It converges to $1.$ However

$$f_n(x_n)=\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n\to e^{-1}\ne 1=f(1).$$

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you also know if the converse holds? Assume $f_n \rightarrow f$ pointwise and it has the property that $f_n(x_n) \rightarrow f(x)$ whenever $x_n \rightarrow x$. Does it follow that $f_n$ converges uniformly?

Comment: @djoef Assume the converse and consider $x_n$ with $|f_n(x_n) - f(x_n)| = \|f_n - f\|$. By compactness $x_n$ has a convergent subsequence. Can you obtain a contradiction?